# Predict rare events based on many continuous time series variables

Tags: prediction, rare-events

It seems to be a common practical problem but I didn't find lots of information how to solve it. I want to predict rare events (1x/month) (e.g. a machine breaks) based on sensor data (~100 variables) with a sampling rate of 1 minute. My goal is to predict the machine failure as long as possible before (e.g. 1h-6h) with a certain level of confidence.

My raw data looks like this:

```
Timestamp           Var1    Var2    VarN    Status
...
2016-01-01 12:00    1.2     1000    -0.2    Ok
2016-01-01 12:01    1.6     982     0       Ok
2016-01-01 12:02    1.1     541     -0.1    Failure
...
```

I started with adding new features like the moving average for the last 15min., 30min., 45min, 1h and also the variable changes like Var1[i]-Var1[i-1], etc.

But now I am facing the following problem:

As I want to make a forecast I have to know in advance how many rows before the actual failure event I want to include and label with "Failure", you know what I mean?

It would be very helpful if you can give me some ideas or best practices for that kind of problem, Thanks!